# Best practice memory management for wrapping gross library

Tags: c++, memory-management

The `ooqp` library has been put into use at my workplace. There is a student wrapping it up at the moment and I am wondering about the best way to deal with this. The following is an example of a function utilized by the program:

```
newQpGenSparse( double ** c, int nx,
    int ** irowQ, int nnzQ, int ** jcolQ, double ** dQ,
    double ** xlow, char ** ixlow,
    double ** xupp, char ** ixupp,
    int ** irowA, int nnzA, int ** jcolA, double ** dA,
    double ** b, int my,
    int ** irowC, int nnzC, int ** jcolC, double ** dC,
    double ** clow, int mz, char ** iclow,
    double ** cupp, char ** icupp,
    int * ierr );
```

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~swright/ooqp/ooqp-userguide.pdf

Gross right? The library is written in `c++` so I am looking for a way to smartly manage the memory.

Using raw pointers is necessary  when interfacing with these functions but I was hoping that perhaps a better way to do it would be to use a `std::shared_ptr` and then expose the raw memory to these functions. This has the obvious disadvantage that the usage of the `shared_ptr` will be violated especially if the memory is deleted or edited by the `ooqp` functions.

Is there a better way to handle this other then just being very careful with new and delete?

Comment: `newQpGenSparse` What kind of monstrosity is this? You can use `std::shared_ptr::get` to access the pointer that `shared_ptr` is wrapping.

Comment: @40two yeah, you should see the current state of the wrapper, the student is a `java` programmer so he just creates new memory all the time and passes it in, it never gets deleted.

Comment: Reading the documentation, `newQpGenSparse` allocates the memory and `freeQpGenSparse` frees it. So if you want to use them, then perhaps wrap them in a class whose constructor calls `newQpGenSparse` and destructor calls `freeQpGenSparse` Provide suitable accessor methods to copy the necessary parameters into the allocated storage. Whoever wrote this interface needs to be punched in the head. Hard.

Comment: I urge you to stop this. It's better for him to do the dishes than to code. You could fool him by saying to him "this is a data structures class, here you'll learn about stacks."

Comment: @40two he is just wrapping this library and is new to c/c++, so absolutely not his fault.

Comment: @T.C. This is just an example, there are other functions that are simpler that you need to make your own memory for, but they are not much simpler.

Comment: Personally, I use `unique_ptr` unless there really is a need to share ownership (i.e., two or more parts of the program that refer to the same memory **and** either one may be responsible for cleaning up).  Often I don't even have a need for two parts of the program to refer to the same memory, which makes the decision even easier.

Comment: I'd first simplify this interface into something more workable - e.g., it uses four parameters to describe a sparse matrix. Write a function that takes reference to a `SparseMatrix` object and unpacks it for this ugliness. `SparseMatrix` could then handle its own memory management, probably using `std::vector` internally.

Comment: "This has the obvious disadvantage that the usage of the shared_ptr will be violated especially if the memory is deleted or edited by the ooqp functions." - You need to figure out whether a library function will free the memory you pass to it - it is simply impossible to write correct code if you don't know who's responsible for freeing allocated memory!

Comment: @T.C you should add this as an answer, some detail about how to convert a `std::vector` to `double **` might be needed. Also yeah, on top of the code being unbearable, its documentation of internal functions is not excellent.

Comment: @Ben Well, if you use a `std::vector` then you can't use `double**`. Note that the documentation says that using `newQpGenSparse` to allocate memory is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes!  The obvious answer is to refactor the library to **not do it like that**.  If that's impossible, you could design a class that stores all the parameter types (hopefully with more descriptive names!).

```
class QPGenSparseWrapper
{
    // Only store params if you want to manage their memory.
    double* Param1;

public:
    QPGenSparseWrapper(const double* param1, const int param2 /* , ... */, param16 = 22) :
        Param1(param1),
    {
        newQpGenSparse(&Param1, param2 /* , ... */, param16);
    }

    virtual ~QPGenSparseWrapper()
    {
        freeQpGenSparse(/* params */);

        // If no corresponding free, use smart pointers or manual delete.
    }

    void Run(/* more params?!? */)
    {
        // I hope you know what goes here.
    }
};
```

It almost goes without saying that you should provide sane defaults to as many of these parameters as possible in order to spare such heartache to future users.

Comment: Yeah, it is impossible to re factor the library. This is good, but it is sort of what we are doing. I guess the question is more about how do we handle the memory that the crazy functions allocate in a smart way. +1 for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the library function uses pointers instead of references. I don't know how many similar functions do you have but if there are a lot then this idea may saves you a lot of coding.

 This way you can use `std::shared_ptr` and forget the `freeQpGenSparse` function.

```
template<class T>
struct arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type { typedef T result; };
template<class T>
struct arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<T*> { typedef T& result; };
template<class T>
struct arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<T**> { typedef std::shared_ptr<T>& result; }; // or unique_ptr

template<class T>
struct arg_value_setter_base {
    arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<T>& m_value;
    T m_new_value;
    T& get() { return m_new_value; }
};

template<class T>
struct arg_value_setter : public arg_value_setter_base<T> {
    arg_value_setter(arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<T>& value) : m_value(value), m_new_value(value) {}
    ~arg_value_setter() { }
};
template<class T>
struct arg_value_setter<T*> : public arg_value_setter_base<T*> {
    arg_value_setter(arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<T>& value) : m_value(value), m_new_value(null_ptr) {}
    ~arg_value_setter() { m_value = *m_new_value; }
};
template<class T>
struct arg_value_setter<T**> : public arg_value_setter_base<T**> {
    arg_value_setter(arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<T>& value) : m_value(value), m_new_value(null_ptr) {}
    ~arg_value_setter() { m_value.reset(*m_new_value); }
};

#define CREATE_WRAPPER_FOR_OOQP_ALLOC_FUNCTION(ret_type, function_name, arg_sequence) \
/* use boost preprocessor macros to get the following result. You just have to use BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I 3 times. I will leave this job for you. */

void newQpGenSparseWrapper(
    arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<double **>::result arg_0, // std::shared_ptr<double>& arg_0
    arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<int>::result arg_1, 
    arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<int **>::result arg_2, // std::shared_ptr<int>& arg_2
    .....,
    arg_type_to_wrapper_arg_type<int *>::result arg_x // int& arg_x
    )
{
    arg_value_setter<double **> arg_setter_0(arg_0); 
    arg_value_setter<int> arg_setter_1(arg_1); 
    arg_value_setter<int **> arg_setter_2(arg_2); 
    .....,
    arg_value_setter<int *> arg_setter_x(arg_x);
    // TODO: you may want to avoid the assignment in case of the failure of the function to prevent shared_ptr from getting an invalid pointer 
    return newQpGenSparse(arg_setter_0.get(), arg_setter_1.get(), arg_setter_2.get(), .... , arg_setter_x.get());
}
```

Now you just have to write a single line of code for every function you want to wrap:

```
CREATE_WRAPPER_FOR_OOQP_ALLOC_FUNCTION(void, newQpGenSparse, (double **)(int)(int **) .... (int *) );
```